# Using a regex pattern to find revision numbers from a svn merge

Tags: regex, svn, diff, svn-merge

```
svn diff -rXX:HEAD
```

Will give me a format like this, if there has been a merge between those revisions:

```
Merged /<branch>:rXXX,XXX-XXX
or
Merged /<branch>:rXXX
```

I'm not very familiar with regex and am trying to put together a pattern which will match all the numbers (merged revision numbers) AFTER matching the "Merged /branch:r" part.

So far I have this to match the first part:
    [Mm]erged.*[a-zA-Z]:r

Thanks in adv. for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/[Mm]erged.*:r([\d,-]+)/
```

The numbers you want will be in the first capture group result.

Comment: Though you'll have to strip the `-` out of the first capture group in the case of ranges but still should work

Comment: This works great! I had something similar when experimenting, though I had a second pair of parenthesis wrapping the entire thing. Now I understand this a bit better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/[Mm]erged.*?:r(\d+)(?:,(\d+)-(\d+))?/
```

The numbers will all be in separate capture groups - the first will always be there, the second and third are optional.